# Thrift TFramedTransport: How can we change the frame size

Tags: networking, xamarin, thrift, transport

I am trying to use Thrift to send file in chunk to server but if I use a large chunk the service can't reach to the server. If I use too small chunk that would too slow. Is there a way to change the frame size for TFramedTransport or what is the maximum framed size was TFramedTransport. I am writing in C# on android.

Comment: What does "can't reach to the server" mean eaxctly? Any error messages? And what language is the server end written in?

Comment: There was no exception. The service on the server couldn't get called after upload few 300kbyte of data each time. If I lower the chunk, the upload is fine. I saw in TFramedTransport has default framed size so I guess that is the issue. Both are written in C#